# Como unificar todas as colunas DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Gostaria de juntar todas as células(colunas) de uma linha (row) de uma DataGridview, ou seja, gostaria de ter uma linha sem bordas laterais nas células.

Algo no estilo:

```
DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleHorizontal
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, isso não deve ocorrer para todas as linhas da DataGridView.

Comment: Como você esta populando sua DataGridview?